# Authentication by AD on a PLAY app

Tags: authentication, jboss, playframework, active-directory, playframework-2.0

we have a web based app using play 2.2.3 framework deployed on jboss 8 Linux platform (wildfly), and we would like to implement a SSO authentication using AD. What is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can authenticate to AD using LDAP.

Personally I've used [UnboundIDs LDAP SDK](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldapsdk/) successfully in Play projects, but basically any LDAP library should work well to do a simple bind.

Comment: LDAP is indeed the language to communicate:-). How did you got the username on the request?

Comment: In our case, we just took the username from the submitted login form and authenticated using that.